# Unwanted duplication with gradient background in CSS

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I'm creating a CSS stylesheet for a webpage. I want a gradient background for the whole webpage, but I can't figure out how to get the gradient to cover the whole webpage. Right now, the gradient is in the form of a typical banner which is replicated down through the website, like one "bar" on top of the other.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

The code I have so far:

```css
body {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FBFF94), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));
}
```

Comment: Try using  background-size:cover;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of both earlier answers should work :

```
body {
min-height: 100vh;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left bottom, #FBFF94, #00A3EF);
background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #FBFF94, #00A3EF);
}
```

Or alternatively :

```
body {
height: 100vh;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left bottom, #FBFF94, #00A3EF);
background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #FBFF94, #00A3EF);
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use VH Unit**, which is a Vertical Height.

Consider

> 100vh = 100%.

```
body {

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FBFF94), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

    height:100vh; /* vh = Vertical Height */
}
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepvirani/8ba1hy2x/1/)

Comment: Actually, 100vh isn't equal to 100% if there is a horizontal scrollbar. The abbreviation is for Viewport Height.

Comment: Instead of mentioning `height` use `background-size: auto 100vh`.

Answer (score 0):

`height` is not set on `body`. This should be helpful:

```css
body{
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left bottom, #FBFF94, #00A3EF);
}
```

And maybe you’d want another `margin:0;` there as well.

But then again using `%` for `height` won’t always be successful, which is why you’ll probably want to use `vh` instead.

Comment: I’d like to know why I’ve earned the downvote on that answer. If it’s because of the `%` unit and the `vh` unit: I’ve added that.

Comment: Wasn't quite the correct answer but didn't really deserve the downvote (wasn't me, I'll equal it out). Syntax for the gradient is much better at least.

Comment: The thing is: I tried my code, it worked for me, so I submitted it…